# Responsivevoice.js can be used offline?

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, responsivevoice

Has anyone ever tried responsivevoice.js without an internet connection in Windows 10 with Google Chrome browser?

I tried responsivevoice.js can run smoothly without using internet connection in OS X (Macbook), but it does not occur in Windows 10 with Google Chrome browser.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be used just keep copy of it downloaded

Comment: It doesn't work. ResponsiveVoice relies on the OS's text-to-speech, which means that on Apple devices almost all languages will work, while on Windows and Android only the system language will work.